# jQuery append showing variable behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's my button that calls the try again function

```js
function tryagain(context) {
  //alert(context.parent());
  var somedata = context.parent().parent().find('td')[0].innerHTML;

  //alert(somedata);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "checkagain.php",
    data: {
      somedata: somedata
    },
    success: function (data) {
      var grandparent = context.parent().parent();
      var parent = context.parent();

      context.remove();
      parent.remove(); * * grandparent.append("<td>" + data + "</td>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='tryagain($(this))' class='btn btn-danger'></button>
```

When I append the td with grandparent, sometimes it appends it fine and most times it just adds another empty td at the end as attached in picture provided data is not empty.
[image]

Comment: add your html code or create jsfiddle

Comment: are you trying to clear and repopulate IMEI and status on `tryagain`?

Comment: Any JS errors that are occurring?

Comment: Alright, a few times, empty data is being returned but I don't see how that should cause the above behavior